# How to create a IDA FLIRT signature for a PPC library?

Tags: ida, tools, elf, static-analysis, flirt-signatures

I'd like to create a IDA FLIRT signature for the following PPC uClibc library:

```
libuClibc-0.9.15.so: ELF 32-bit MSB shared object, PowerPC or cisco 4500, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.0.0, stripped
```

I got the FLAIR tools from hex-rays but didn't manage to create the .sig file.
If I understood correctly, a `.pat` file must be created first, from which a `.sig` file can be created then. I tried `./pelf.exe libuClibc-0.9.15.so`, but this only returned an 'invalid input file' error.

How can I create a FLIRT signature from this library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you can only create the `.pat` files from statically linked libraries using the method you describe. It appears your file is dynamically linked (that would explain the 'invalid input file' message)

You can give a try to [this IDAPython plugin](https://github.com/fireeye/flare-ida/blob/master/python/flare/idb2pat.py). A good explanation from its author can be found [here](https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2015/01/flare_ida_pro_script.html)

Good luck!